# How to get the actual file name in exception message in Databricks?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to figure out, how to get the actual file/module name in exception message in Databricks.

```
import traceback
def bad():
  print("hello")
  a = 1/0

def main():
  try:
    bad()
  except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

main()
```

When I run this the exception message I get like -

```
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<command-162594828857243>", line 8, in main
    bad()
  File "<command-162594828857243>", line 4, in bad
    a = 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

The `"<command-162594828857243>"` doesn't help at the time of debugging. I want the actual file/module name there.

Comment: Would `traceback.print_stack()` work better?

Comment: @Jon No, it prints additional stack-trace which I don't need also `command ...` stays.